# dyld symbol not found osm2pgsql to TileMill

Tags: postgis, tilemill

I am trying to get an osm.pbf file into TileMill, but terminal is throwing the error "dyld: symbol not found"

```
  dyld: Symbol not found: __ZN4geos4geom10CoordinateD1Ev
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/osm2pgsql
  Expected in: /Library/Frameworks/GEOS.framework/Versions/3/GEOS
  in /usr/local/bin/osm2pgsql
```

I recently reinstalled TileMill and it's now throwing me this error. I don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message says that your executable (osm2pgsql) isn't finding a reference to a shared library.  Perhaps it's not finding the shared library itself.

From a command prompt:

1) Check which shared libraries osm2pgsql needs:

```
cd /usr/local/bin
ldd osm2pgsql
  <= This will print a list of shared libraries, and the expected paths
```

2) See if your GEOS.framework directory exists, and has the (missing?) libraries

```
cd /Library/Frameworks/GEOS.framework/Versions/3/GEOS
ls -lR | less
```

3) Set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to point to your correct GEOS.framework library directory

... OR ...

Re-install GEOS.framework.

4) Here's the main page for GEOS.framework:

http://trac.osgeo.org/geos/

5) Here's additional information on $LD_LIBRARY_PATH and configuration for Linux shared libraries:

http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html